# How to solve Java compiler-error "cannot find symbol"?

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors

I'm just starting to learn how to code in Java.

#### Task

I made a small program in the online platform [*replit*](https://replit.com/).
The program compares two `int`s:

- whether they are equal or not
- which one is greater and which one is the smaller number

#### Errors

I stumbled into these errors when compiling:

```
Main.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
   System.out.println("El mayor es " + may);
                                       ^
 symbol:   variable may
 location: class Main

Main.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
   System.out.println("El menor es " + men);
                                       ^
 symbol:   variable men
 location: class Main

2 errors
```

#### My code

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;
    if (b==a)
    {
      System.out.println("Both digits are equivalent");
    }
    else 
    {
      if (b>a)
      {
        int may = b;//may stands for the position of the greater number
        int men = a;//men stands for the position of the smaller number
      }
      else 
      {
        int may = a;
        int men = b;
      }
      System.out.println("the bigger number is " + may);
      System.out.println("the smaller number is " + men);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited the question to make the problem clear and reproducible. I can read following question: "How to solve a Java compiler-error  ..." . Please do required [research for `[java] cannot find symbol` on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20cannot%20find%20symbol) and you will find answers. Because this compiler-error "cannot find symbol" is quite common for Java newbies.

Comment: thanks for the edit, I'm quite new to the language so I didn't really know how to title it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`may` and `men` are not within the scope of your last two print statements. There are different solutions. One of them would be to declare the variables outside of the `if` statement. **EDIT TO SHOW DECLARATION**: I haven't written java in some time but I believe the declaration is like:

```
...
else
{
  int may;
  int men;
  if (b>a)
  {
     may = b;
     men = a;
  }
  else
  {
     may = a;
     men = b;
  }
// print statements
```

Comment: The thing is I cant put them outside the if statement because that is kind of the main function that makes up the code or at least I don't know how to code the def of the variables outside the if statement. If you had another solution, it would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer to show declaration outside of `if` statement. Please give it a try and let me know if that works.

Comment: Newbies to programming and Java probably want know the term "scope". So they might not understand what means for a "symbol" or variable to be  "in scope" or "outside scope". Could you explain, to make it clear?

Comment: The difference between terms "declare" (create), "assign" (write) or "reference" (read) might explain where to introduce and where to use a variable (scope, location in code).

Comment: Thanks for the answers and explanations. It worked out fine and I could finally finish my homework :)